# Wordpress post redirecting to another post, when it shouldn't be

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have one post that works fine.
https://www.bingotastic.com/bgo/

Then I have a second post.
https://www.bingotastic.com/gala-bingo/

The problem is that the second post is directing to the first for no reason. I have disabled plugins, looked over the htaccess file, and looked inside the theme files. I can not find any reason why this would happen. From what I can tell, it is just this one post that is doing it, and it also seems that it is not redirecting from gala-bingo, to bgo, it is just going straight to bgo. If I change the url from gala-bingo, to anything else, even if I just add a letter at the end, then the page loads correctly. If I change the bgo url to anything, the gala-bingo url still directs to that page. I can not find anything that works using Google, so I thought I would ask here.

How do I stop this post from directing to the other, but keep the urls the way they are?

Comment: You cleared the cache? Test it, change the permalink of both pages and see if it still redirects.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have removed the plugins, I suggest going to the settings->permalinks page in your dashboard and click "save changes".
By doing this it will rebuild your rewrite rules and remove any that were added by old plugins.
It currently happens for me, but make sure you clear cache ect before checking.